# If two options are the same go to next option in second select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This one has stumped me. If you have two select tags (see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tULPU/1/)), both with all of the same options, how would you write a script to go the next option in the second select tag, if the user selects the same option in both selects.

Comment: I tried identifying the two by id, and then using an if statement to read which one was selected in both, and if they were the same… well, that was where I got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom Hubbard's solution didn't work for me, the values switched around strangely at times. For me this worked:

```
$(function() {
    $('.salary-select').change(function() {
        if($('#salary1').val() == $('#salary2').val() ) {
            $("#salary2")[0].selectedIndex+=1;
        }
    });
});
```

You'd need to add something you check you didn't select the last value in both lists, however.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4aLc/2/

Comment: Agreed, mine was more "in spirit". This is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think that rather than change the salary on the user (which isn't the best user experience), you alert the user to the need for a change.  Going to the next item on the list may not be what the user wants.  I suggest something like this

```
$('#salary2').change(function(){
    var a = $('#salary1').val();
    var b = $('#salary2').val();
    if(a==b){
    alert('Your salaries match. Please change the range.')
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tULPU/4/

**EDIT**

Also, if you wanted to make it so that the user is alerted whenever there is a match, whatever order they choose, switch the selector to `$('#salary1, #salary2')`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tULPU/8/

Comment: I agree that switching on the user gives a bit of a "whu-- what just happened?" feel. +1!

Comment: True, that code is erroneous when you change the first, and then the second to match it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

This will be erroneous if both entries are the last.

```
if($("#salary1")[0].selectdIndex === $("#salary2")[0].selectdIndex){
    $("#salary2")[0].selectedIndex+=1;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle please?